# uses undefined struct 'asn1_object_st'

Tags: openssl

I am compiling OpenSSL1.1.1 with Visual Studio 2017 on windows 10.

I am using below code in my .cpp file

```
 #include <openssl/ossl_typ.h>
 func(){
 ASN1_OBJECT obj;
 }
```

I am getting error:

error C2079: 'obj' uses undefined struct 'asn1_object_st'

I have included "openssl/ossl_typ.h" in my file.

I am giving openssl "-IC:\openssl-1.1.1w\include" option to "cl" command

Please let me know how to fix above compilation error..